# Remove content/text that ISN'T wrapped in html tags, in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm building a html scraper which is successfully parsing a url and returning just the p, img and a tags as required to the var $content.

However, certain URLS end up placing erroneous javascript in the html, so my $content var contains:

```html
<p>This is Paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is Paragraph 2</p>
<img src="/Path/To/Img">
";document.getElementById('Rogue Broken Javascript Text.14155741')
<p>This is Paragraph 3</p>
```

How can I remove any content that ***isn't*** wrapped in HTML tags? (ie. sort of the reverse of `strip_tags()`) so I end up with just:

```html
<p>This is Paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is Paragraph 2</p>
<img src="/Path/To/Img">
<p>This is Paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: Could you at least show the code you have so far? Are you using regular expressions to parse DOM?

Comment: I'm not using regular expressions. The var $content contains the upper quoted HTML. I want to sanitize it so that anything **not** in html tags gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't is just an error in your parsing methods? I would simply search for `<p>`, `</p>`, `<a>`, and `</a>` tags, scraping everything between them. Then for img tags, you only scrape what is between `<img` and the next `>`.

If your example above is real output, then I would say there's a mistake in your `<img>` parsing where it's not stopping at the `>`.

Of course, you have to account for badly written HTML also. How you handle it will depend on stuff like how important getting every detail is, or if you can just skip past the bad code.